# Last imported file overwrites statements from previous files. Better ways of specifying imported variables?

Tags: python, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hey stackoverflow community,

i’m new to this forum and to python developing in general and have a problem with Alexa/ Python overriding the similar named variable from different files.

In my language learning skill I want Alexa to specifically link a “start specific practice” intent from the user to a specific practice file and from this file to import an intro, keyword and answer to give back to the user.

My problem with the importing, is that Python takes the last imported file and overrides the statements of the previous files.

I know I could probably change the variable names according to the practices but then wouldn't I have have to create a lot of individual handler functions which link the user intent to a specific file/function and basically look and act all the same?

Is there a better way more efficient of doing the specifying of those variables when importing or inside the functions?

## import files and variables

```
from übung_1 import intro_1, keywords_1, real_1
from übung_2 import intro_1, keywords_1, real_1
```

## working with the variables

```
def get_practice_response(practice_number):
    print("get_practice_response")
    session_attributes = {}
    card_title = "Übung"
    number = randint(0, len(keywords_1))
    print(intro_1 + keywords_1[number])
    speech_output = intro_1 + keywords_1[number]
    session_attributes["answer"] = real_1[number]
    session_attributes["practice_number"] = practice_number
    session_attributes["keyword"] = keywords_1[number]
    reprompt_text = "test"
    should_end_session = False
    return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
        card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

I expected giving out the content of the specifically asked file and not variable content from the most recent files.

Sadly I haven't found a solution for this specific problem and hope someone could help me pointing me in the right direction.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Wow... not bad for the first question on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Might be easiest to import the modules like so:

```
import übung_1
import übung_2
```

The refer to the contents as `übung_1.intro_1`, `übung_2.intro_1`, `übung_1.keywords_1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, these two lines

```
from übung_1 import intro_1, keywords_1, real_1
from übung_2 import intro_1, keywords_1, real_1
```

don't work the way you want because the second import overrides the first. This has to happen because you can't have two different variables in the same namespace called `intro_1`.

You can get around this by doing

```
import übung_1 
import übung_2
```

and then in your code you explicitly state the namespace you want:

```
print(übung_1.intro_1 + übung_1.keywords_1[number])
```